# Can C++ boost be used in VxWorks 6.9 kernel space

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, vxworks

I am trying to use boost (v 1.77.0) in the vxWorks kernel space (not RPC).

The vxWorks version is 6.9. The compiler is `ccarm`:

> ccarm.exe (Wind River VxWorks G++ 4.3-386) 4.3.3

Initially the error was that the file `<cstdio>` that is included by `vxworks.hpp` is not found. I added the path `$(WIND_BASE)/target/usr/h` to the list of include paths (`-I`) which actually includes the file, but that caused compilation errors that have to do with symbol redefinition. The first symbol to fail was `fpos_t` which is defined in both `stdio.h` and as a macro in `vxTypes.h` (originally from `vxTypesBase.h`).

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2709083) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1481768) that was linked by the question, but neither succeeded in fixing the issue. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4993152/2176845) question didn't provide useful information for this issue either.

Adding the compilation flag `-std=c++0x` didn't solve the issue either (nor did I expect it to, as the root cause was a missing file).

It would appear from [here](https://harmonicss.co.uk/vxworks/building-and-running-vxworks-7-boost-c-applications/) that some boost libraries can be built into the kernel image, but all that I really need is a small subset of header-only libraries. I don't want to link the libraries into the kernel image itself.

1. Has anyone successfully used boost in the vxWorks kernel space?
2. Is there a specific boost build that I should be doing in order to get the correct macros defined?